# "Free" tickets?

Tags: password, steganography

Today I received an email from a friend:

```
Hi Bob,

I managed to get those concert tickets you wanted so badly! Your ticket is in the first
attachment. However, since it took me quite a while to get them, I'm not just going to give
you the ticket. It's protected with a 10-character password. You can use the second
attachment to figure out the password. Good luck! :)

John.
```

The concert is in a few days, and I really want to go! Can you help me figure out what the password (10 characters) is? The second attachment is a text file, but it looks like gibberish to me. Maybe you can figure out what it means...

> You! Tito having another idea; zero Kelvin yields dreadful audio, random system transform and epsilon juxtaposition. HIV treatment XII (lukewarm overflow at nonconform dynamic) overview in vanilla roentgenographic. Telegram in desk, sushi dish is calamari. New venogram: nov, Anna Layton. Extra kiwi? Ask yourself: lemon cream extraction mastership anyhow?

---

*Hint:*
Since there's not much time left, John gave me a hint today. He said:

> Use what's in the text file to find what is not...

---

*Hint:*
Today I asked him for another hint. He told me:

> "You want another hint already? Just give me some space."
>  It's not like we're in a relationship or something. Apparently space is important to him...

---

*Hint:*
John gave me a new hint!

> The words themselves won't tell you anything, try reading between the... lines? Hmmm, no, not between the lines. Also, don't mind the punctuation, you don't need it.

---

*Hint:*
A new hint!

> Have you heard of that research showing that the order of the letters in a word doesn't matter, as long as the last and the first letter are correct? Fascinating...

Comment: Is the cipher tag applicable here?

Comment: @Moose No, the cipher tag is not applicable. I thought about adding the stenography tag, but I'm not 100% sure if that one's applicable.

Comment: Space as in outer space or the _other_ space?

Comment: @Wu33o, I'm guessing you missed the concert.

Comment: Post the original text markup please i guess Whitespaces/newlines are important here.

Comment: @SvenB If they would be important I would've posted the original text markup already. Doesn't really make sense to post an (almost) unsolvable puzzle, right?

Comment: @wu33o Oh i thought your friend Made the riddle

Comment: With the new hint: here are the first and last letters of the words: "YuTohgariazoKnysdlaormsmtmadenjnHVttXIlmowatnmdcowinvarcTmindksidhisciNwvmnvAaLnEakiAkyflncmenmpaw"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have a possible answer:

> John said to think about spaces between things. 
>  
>  **Step 1:** 
>   
>  The letters adjacent to each space in the text form a state abbreviation: 
>  
>  
>  1.   Yo[u T]ito -> UT (Utah ) 
>  2.   OH (Ohio) 
>  3.   GA (Georgia) 
>  4.   RI (Rhode Island) 
>  5.   AZ (Arizona) 
>  6.   OK (Oklahoma) 
>  7.   NY (New York) 
>  8.   SD (South Dakota) 
>  9.   LA (Louisiana) 
>  10.  OR (Oregon) 
>  11.  MS (Mississippi) 
>  12.  MT (Montana) 
>  13.  MA (Massachusetts) 
>  14.  DE (Delaware) 
>  15.  NJ (New Jersey) 
>  16.  NH (New Hampshire) 
>  17.  VT (Vermont)  
>  18.  TX (Texas) 
>  19.  Il (Illinois) 
>  20.  MO (Missouri) 
>  21.  WA (Washington) 
>  22.  TN (Tennessee) 
>  23.  MD (Maryland) 
>  24.  CO (Colorado) 
>  25.  WI (Wisconsin) 
>  26.  NV (Nevada) 
>  27.  AR (Arkansas) 
>  28.  CT (Connecticut)  
>  29.  MI (Michigan) 
>  30.  ND (North Dakota) 
>  31.  KS (Kansas) 
>  32.  ID (Idaho) 
>  33.  HI (Hawaii) 
>  34.  SC (South Carolina)  
>  35.  IN (Indiana) 
>  36.  WV (West Virginia)  
>  37.  MN (Minnesota) 
>  38.  VA (Virginia) 
>  39.  AL (Alabama) 
>  40.  NE (Nebraska) 
>  41.  AK (Alaska) 
>  42.  IA (Iowa) 
>  43.  KY (Kentucky) 
>  44.  FL (Florida) 
>  45.  NC (North Carolina)  
>  46.  ME (Maine) 
>  47.  NM (New Mexico) 
>  48.  PA (Pennsylvania) 
>  EDIT: and 49 WY (Wyoming) from the last and first letters in the text 
>  **Step 2:**  
>  
>  With 49 states listed, we can see there is 1 missing. This is our password
>  
>  
>  
>  ***CALIFORNIA***

Edit:  Thanks to Dan and Sora for pointing me towards a more logical conclusion!

Comment: I think your findings are interesting. But then I would think the answer would be simply California.

Comment: I think you've got it! Just wrap around the end of the very last word to the start of the first word, eliminate one of your two remaining, and presto!

Comment: That's it Dan and Sora!  Never thought to wrap around the whole thing.  Will edit

Comment: And welcome to Puzzling, by the way. Very nice first answer!

Comment: That's it! Well done :)

Answer (score 4):

Massive Stretch:

> youcandoit

Because:

> The letters 'B' and 'Q' are the only English alphabet characters missing from the text and the DIY store B&Q had the slogan 'You can do it when you B&Q it'

Comment: I almost guessed "quarterback" for the same reason, but alas it has 11 characters.  Must be more to it, since a more reasonable-sounding note could be written that would have the same property.

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint

> Use what's in the text file to find what is not...

I think the password is

> 1234567890

because

> we see numbers in the text file, but only as words ("zero") or roman numerals ("XII"), and not arabic numerals. And it just so happens the Arabic numeral system consists of 10 digits, from 1 to 0 (when looking at a keyboard from left to right), or 0 to 9 (from lowest to highest).

Answer (score 1):

Don't have an answer, just sharing my work in case it helps, even to just rule stuff out.

The only letters missing from the note entirely are

> **B** and **Q**.

First letters of every word are

> ythaizkydarstaejhtxloandoivrtidsdicnvnalekaylcema
>
>  And so the letters that don't begin any words are **bfgpquw**

Letter counts (case-insensitive)

> `a 30
>  b 0
>  c 6
>  d 10
>  e 27
>  f 5
>  g 5
>  h 8
>  i 26
>  j 1
>  k 5
>  l 13
>  m 13
>  n 27
>  o 25
>  p 4
>  q 0
>  r 21
>  s 15
>  t 18
>  u 7
>  v 9
>  w 6
>  x 4
>  y 7
>  z 1`

I tried using

> the first parts of sentences to eliminate letters from the second, or vice versa, but with no obvious success.

There are suspicious bits of the message, such as

> "New venogram: nov, Anna" which has a number of shared letters in close proximity, as well as having "Anna" and "gram" near one another.

It's hard to imagine that the

> *content* of the message is important, given the nonsensical nature of it, but somehow it tells us what is *not* in the text file (as per the hint).

Comment: I get the feeling that the use of the punctuation marks are also important.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a jumping off point

> The letter counts for each word are   3 4 6 7 4 4 6 6 8 5 6 6 9 3 7 13 3 9 3 8 8 2 10 7 8 2 7 16 8 2 4 5 4 2 8 3 8 3 4 6 5 4 3 8 5 5 10 10 6

and

> We can use alphabet positioning to get the characters cdfgddffhefficgmcichhbjghbgphbdedbhchcdfedcheejjf. There are 11 letters which show up in that string, they are BCDEFGHIJMP.

Answer (score -1):

I highly doubt it is the answer but could it be:

> fortyeight  - the number of space characters there are in the text.

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in a detailed explanation as to why you think it is correct, citing the information in the question? Thanks!

Comment: What is there not to understand? Count the number of spaces in the text and it equals 48. Based on the first two hints it could be possible the answer lies with spaces.

Comment: Is there content in the question itself - excluding hints - that leads you to believe that this answer should be the correct one? If so, which lines, and what led you to the conclusion that this answer is probably correct?

Comment: No. Hence the 'highly doubt it'.

Comment: But the number is "fo**u**rty-eight".

Comment: It depends which spelling you use and one of the clues said punctuation wasn't important. Why are we debating this? I only answered with that as I made an observation and there were no other solid leads. I made it clear it was likely wrong. The final clue makes it obvious where to look but I didn't have that clue and didn't notice the pattern as I'm not familiar with state abbreviations.